# How to convert Excel Date/Time format to include ms and timezone for Dataloader

Tags: excel, timestamp, salesforce, timestamp-with-timezone

I have timestamps that need to be converted to a specific format for the purposes of Salesforce's Dataloader. I'm thinking of adding a column in Excel to change the formatting.

Here's an example:

```
1/23/2017 10:54:21 AM
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
01/23/2017T10:54:21.000GMT-4:00
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a tiny bit crude, but you can construct a string in the new column by doing this, where A1 is the original value:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyyThh:MM:SS"),".000GMT-4:00")
```

There are ways of getting the current local timezone if you want, but for my purposes it's not needed.

This can also handle cases where the original formatting uses dashes instead of slashes to separate the date.

Comment: Did you ask the question to answer it immediately? You asked and answered within the same minute...?

Comment: I was in the process of posting the question when I discovered the answer. Thought it might be useful to someone else in the future. SO has a Q&A option for this sort of thing....

Comment: Do you have a reference for ISO 8601 allowing dates in that format?  The references I've seen show only minor variations on yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss -04:00

Comment: You're right – I'm not sure what the spec is that Dataloader is using but I fixed the summary to drop reference to ISO 8601.